# sorting UI for ranked-model gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, activerecord

I'm trying to make a sorting UI work with gem `ranked-model`.

Gemfile:

```
gem 'ranked-model'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails' #for drag-and-drop
```

application.js:

```
//= require jquery-ui/widgets/sortable
```

lesson.rb:

`class Lesson < ApplicationRecord
  include RankedModel
  ranks :row_order
end`

lessons_controller.rb - added sort function:

```
class LessonsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @lessons = Lesson.rank(:row_order)
  end

  def sort
    lesson = Lesson.find(params[:lesson_id])
    lesson.update(lesson_params)
    render body: nil
  end

  private
    def lesson_params
      params.require(:lesson).permit(:name, :row_order_position)
    end
end
```

routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :lessons do
    put :sort
  end
end
```

so that the routes look like this:

[image: routes]

lessons.html.haml:

```
%h1 Lessons
%table.table
  %thead
    %tr
      %th Name
  %tbody#item{"data-model_name": "lesson.class.name.underscore", "data-update_url": "lesson_sort_path(lesson)"}
    - @lessons.each do |lesson|
      %tr
        %td= lesson.name
```

table_sort.js:

```
$(function(){
  $('#item').sortable({
    update: function(e, ui){
      var item = ui.item;
      var item_data = item.data();
      var params = {_method: 'put'};
      params[item_data.modelName] = { row_order_position: item.index() }
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: item_data.updateUrl,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: params
      });
    }
  });
});
```

**The sorting works, however it is not persisted and I get the following error in the logs. Any idea how to persist the sorting?**

[image: logs]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working solution I came up with.

The view:

```
.list-group.lesson-sortable
  - @lessons.each do |lesson|
    = content_tag "div", id: "lesson-#{lesson.id}", data: { model_name: lesson.class.name.underscore, update_url: lesson_sort_path(lesson)} do
      = lesson.name
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
  $('.lesson-sortable').sortable({
    update: function(e, ui){
      let item = ui.item;
      let item_data = item.data();
      let params = {_method: 'put'};
      params[item_data.modelName] = { row_order_position: item.index() }
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: item_data.updateUrl,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: params
      });
    },
    stop: function(e, ui){
      console.log("stop called when finishing sort of cards");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  %tbody#item{"data-model_name": "lesson.class.name.underscore", "data-update_url": "lesson_sort_path(lesson)"}
- @lessons.each do |lesson|
```

You should invert the two lines, as `lessor_sort_path(lesson)` requires `lesson` variable. That was why you get the wrong `PUT /lessons/` path when updating. Maybe something like (I'm not familiar with Haml):

```
  %tbody#item
- @lessons.each do |lesson|
  %tr{"data-model_name": "lesson.class.name.underscore", "data-update_url": "lesson_sort_path(lesson)"}
```

Comment: yeah, indeed that was a stupid mistake to put `lesson` logic before `lesson` variable is introduced. althrough it didn't make the code work